# windows cluster - SSH seems to be failing

Tags: windows, configuration, ssh, cluster-computing

Two physical systems, each is running Server 2008
Installed DataStax Community (version 2.0.7 64-bit) on each (that is the version number in the DataStax package I downloaded according to the file name)
OpCenter running locally shows a running 1 node cluster.  I can execute IO on the system at the command line (using cassandra-stress)
The system names are "5017-cassandra-1" and "5017-cassandra-2"

I'd like to create a cluster in which both nodes participate.  This is not a production environment (I'm just trying to learn).

From OpCenter on 5017-cassandra-1 I go to Nodes (I see 1 node of course), Add Nodes.
I leave the "Package" drop down as default (but the latest version shown in the drop down is 2.0.6), enter the IP address of 5017-cassandra-2.  I add the Administrator user name and password in the "Node Creditials (sudo)" fields and press "Add Nodes" and get:

```
Error provisioning cluster: Unable to SSH to some of the hosts

Unable to SSH to 10.108.14.224:
global name 'get_output' is not defined
```

Reading that I needed to add OpenSSL - I installed the runtime redistributables (on both system) and Win64 OpenSSL-1_0_1h.

The error persists.

any suggestions or link to a step-by-step would be appreciated.

Comment: I have the same issue... Any luck?